# Google indexing of AJAX site: how to transition from _escaped_fragment_ method?

Tags: ajax, seo, single-page-application, google-search

My site currently uses hashbang URLs with the Google deprecated recommendation of having a static page served when requesting with _escaped_fragment_ query parameter.

Example static pre-generate page using deprecate method:

> https://tweepi.com/app/#!/help is statically served when requesting https://tweepi.com/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/help

I am building a dynamic page and do not want to keep regenerating a static HTML file. I read [Google's new recommendation](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and it says simply do not disallow Googlebot from crawling your site's CSS or JS files.

Assuming a new dynamic page with the URL https://tweepi.com/app/#!/reviews, **what status code should the following URL return to ensure best SEO results when Google/Bing crawls my site?** 404? 500? 301 redirect?

> https://tweepi.com/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/reviews

Answer (score 0):

For SEO bots: html snapshot for url: `https://tweepi.com/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/reviews`, (status code 200) that's mean nothing special for `https://tweepi.com/app/#!/reviews`

Users: 404 for `https://tweepi.com/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/reviews`